# How to add two columns with years on google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: google sheets]

Can anyone please help me achieve this on google sheets? Need to find the values in the red color cell

Comment: So, which columns (A, B, C or D) do you want to add (e.g. A+C or B+C or...) and what is the expected result?

Comment: @marikamitsos I only have A and B columns need to find column C and D

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 That is the screen shot of the sheet where column C and column D is blank

Comment: @player0 I need to find out what was the employee present experience in the company and total experience in his life. I only have column A and B data points.

Comment: There should be `3.0`, not `2.10`, correct?

Comment: @kishkin 2.9 years + .1 years is 2.10 which is 2 years 10 months and not 3 years

Comment: That is uncanny... 0.5 of a year is not 5 months, it is half a year, so 6 months. Why would you want 2.9 to be 2 years and 9 months? Don't you want to use it as a number later? You won't be able to... (without errors)

Comment: @murali best of luck, mate! I will have nothing to do with this. Somebody might use it and it will only bring people suffering and pain.

Comment: As also mentioned by @kishkin, this is definitely not the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

First, in column C you need to find the date difference between `TODAY` and the `date of joining`, split into years and months, and then concatenate both. You could use this formula for that:

```
=CONCATENATE(QUOTIENT(DATEDIF(DATEVALUE(A2), TODAY(), "YM"), 12), "-", MOD(DATEDIF(DATEVALUE(A2), TODAY(), "YM"),12))
```

[image]

Second, in column D, you have to sum the values before and after the separator from columns B and C (`-`). You could use this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(VALUE(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1)) + VALUE(LEFT(C2, FIND("-",C2)-1)), "-", VALUE(REPLACE(B2,1,FIND("-",B2),"") + VALUE(REPLACE(C2,1,FIND("-",B2),"") )))
```

[image]

#### Note:

As a separator between years and months, I've used `-` instead of `.`. I very much recommend not using `.`, since this has the same format as a decimal number and can lead to confusion, as you can see in the comments below your question.